# What should be used bool or exception?

Tags: java, exception, boolean

It's not real problem I'm just curious.

For example I'm creating operations for API is it better to use:

```
public bool Login(string username, string password);
```

And return **false** when login fail.
Or I should rather use:

```
public void Login(string username, string password);
```

And return some my exception, like LoginFailedException?
What is better and why?

Comment: Generally it depends on your use, but as far is the Login concerned, boolean is always preferred. I have never seen throwing an exception if Login fails.

Comment: @JNL So exceptions should be used only for control errors, not things like login, which will often fail?

Comment: For every one method returning bool, there are fifty programmers that ignored its return value.   If a failed login is fatal to an app, it should be, then don't be modest about reporting failure.  The one advantage of using bool is that an attacker will have a harder time cracking passwords.  Don't do that either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should raise an `Exception` when something not expected happens.

In your case if a user is logging in it is not unexpected that the procedure fails, he/she might have inserted a wrong password or used a wrong username password combination.
It would be exceptional if, for example, the database is not found.

Exceptions should not be used as flow control structures, but to handle those edge, unexpected cases that could happen outside the normal flow of an application.

Be sure though to return a proper response, in JSON it could be something like

```
{
  "result": "failure",
  "message": "username and/or password not matching to any user"
}
```

because a simple false is not informative at all.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is to use exceptions to catch all unusual behavior of login but return true or false to know whether the login was successful.

Answer (score 0):

A method should use a return value to indicate that it failed for a reason the *immediate calling code* will be able to handle usefully, or throw an exception if it failed for a reason the immediate calling code cannot handle usefully.  If the author of a method doesn't know whether a callers will be able to handle failure, it may be helpful for it to provide a version which will throw in case of any problem, and one which will use a return value to indicate whether any expected failure conditions have occurred.  Trying to log into a remote machine is a scenario where either situation may apply.  If calling code is prepared to e.g. try three different methods of logging on before giving up, it may be more helpful for the first attempts to report failure via return code than for them to throw an exception.  If, however, code is expecting to log into a remote machine and interact with it, a failed log-in attempt may represent a failure of the whole interactive sequence, in which case it might be more helpful for the log-in method to throw an exception rather than requiring the caller to check the log-in method's return code and throw its own exception if it failed.

Note that even if one wants to use a return value to indicate whether something succeeded, a `bool` may not be the best choice.  It may be more helpful to define a class or interface type for that purpose, with a member that indicates whether something worked, and other methods that may provide details of any failure.  One should generally avoid having methods allocate objects needlessly, but one could avoid such allocation in the common case if there were a static "success" instance which the method could return if everything goes normally.  The calling code might look like:

```
result1 = TryLogin(first batch of info/parameters);
if (result1sSucceeded)
  return;

result2 = TryLogin(second batch of info/parameters);
if (result2.succeeded)
  return;

result3 = TryLogin(third batch of info/parameters);
if (result3.succeeded)
  return;

results = new ArrayList<LoginResult>;
results.add(result1);
results.add(result2);
results.add(result3);
throw new RepeatedLoginFailureException(results);
```

If any of the login attempts succeeds, the method will return.  If all three attempts fail, an exception will be thrown with an encapsulated list that indicating the problem reported from each attempt.  A `TryLogin` which succeeds may simply return a reference to a static instance of a class derived from `LoginResult` whose `succeeded` field is `final` and `true`, and the calling code will only have to create a new list object if all three attempts fail.